# Should ntp be running on EOS nodes that p2p to other nodes?

Tags: time

Does the EOSIO software attempt to synchronize the current time between multiple EOS hosts (or nodes), or should NTP be used to manage system time?

Presumably two separate time sync sources could fight with each other.  I see possible evidence of this when I check using ntpq -p, but I run on VM instances and I don't know if some other process is managing system time.